# Dynamically add index to a List

Tags: c#, list, variables, dynamic, runtime

is there any way that I can add a new index to a list dynamically / run-time
like there wasn't any index at first then each time the timer ticks, one index is added to the list (values will be from a static array list).

perhaps something like this ?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lblPulseQuery = from PulseTime in PulseAndTime
                        where Convert.ToInt32(PulseTime.Time) == i
                        select PulseTime;

    foreach (PulseTime PulseTime in lblPulseQuery)
    {
        lblPulse.Text = PulseTime.Pulse + " bps";
    }

    List<string> PulseList = new List<string>();
    PulseList.Add(lblPulse.Text);
    string[] PulseArray = PulseList.ToArray();
}
```

The code above will only change the value of the index instead of adding another index of a different value.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the List PulseList = new List(); is declared inside the timer1_Tick(). Every time the timer ticks, it will just overwrite the value of the PulseList since it will instantiate a new object.

if you want to retain the values of the PulseList, declare it in the class scope so when you add another object, the index will increment.

Comment: ah.. I see, but will the present code work the way I want it after I declare it in the class scope ?

Comment: If you declare the `List<string> PulseList = new List<string>();` in the class scope, yes.